# Возврат из функции массива, содержащего все строки запроса

Tags: php

```
    function GetMessages($id){
    $res = $this->query("SELECT * FROM `chmblog`.`message` WHERE uid='$id' ORDER BY date DESC");
    $arr = array();
    while($temp = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
        $subj = new subject();
        $subj->nick = $temp[1];
        $subj->header = $temp[2];
        $subj->text = $temp[3];
        $subj->date = $temp[4];
        array_push($arr, $subj);
    }
    mysql_free_result($temp);
    return $arr;
}
```

Пытался сделать так, но возвращает все равно только одну (последнюю) строку запроса.

Comment: А Вы уверены, что запрос возвращает больше одной строки? (например, если предположить, что поле `uid` - Unique ID, то результат должен быть предсказуем, а если `uid` - User ID, тогда вам необходимо добавить проверку на количество рядов mysql_num_rows():

Во-первых проверите, надо ли шагать в цикл;
Во-вторых узнаете, сколько реально рядов вернул ваш запрос.

А еще, для вашего примера, удобнее использовать функцию

    mysql_fetch_array();

Comment: Извините, действительно была тупорылая ошибка в том, что запрос возвращал всего одну строку, да и функцию я не ту редактировал, в общем, я нуб(

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал fetch_assoc в нем меньше шансов запутаться в коде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function GetMessages($id){
    $res = $this->query("SELECT * FROM `chmblog`.`message` WHERE uid='$id' ORDER BY date DESC");
    $arr = array();
    $i = 0;
    while($temp = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
        $arr[$i] = new subject();
        $arr[$i]->nick = $temp[1];
        $arr[$i]->header = $temp[2];
        $arr[$i]->text = $temp[3];
        $arr[$i]->date = $temp[4];
        $i++;
    }
    mysql_free_result($temp);
    return $arr;
}
```

Так попробуйте.
ПС. надеюсь у вас безопасные запросы SQL.